# Convert numpy array to dataframe (large number of columns)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How to convert numpy array to pandas dataframe.
To simplify matters, the array only contains 5 values. in practice there are many more.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nparray1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
nparray2 = np.array([2,2,2,6,6])
```

I want to get the following dataframe structure out of nparray1:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5       |
|         |         |         |         |         |
```

In a next step I want to append nparray2 to the dataframe:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5       |
| 2       | 2       | 2       | 6       | 6       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `DataFrame` an then append by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
nparray1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
nparray2 = np.array([2,2,2,6,6])

df = pd.DataFrame([nparray1])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5

df.loc[len(df)] = nparray2
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  2  2  2  6  6
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([nparray1, nparray2])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  2  2  2  6  6
```

EDIT:

If performance is important create 2d array:

```
np.random.seed(2021)
n_arrays = 100
n_columns = 10000
arrays = [
    np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n_columns)
    for n in range(n_arrays)
]


In [41]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(arrays)
919 ms ± 40 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [42]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(arrays))
2.39 ms ± 86.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Another solution:

```
In [43]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame({row_index: row_array for row_index, row_array in enumerate(arrays)}).T
7.16 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This will be very slow if you have a lot of large arrays. Check my answer for a much faster solution - you have to work with columns, not rows.

Comment: you added my answer to your answer? Nice :)

Comment: @gshpychka - Sure, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is column-based, so try to do your operations on whole columns at a time instead of rows, it will be much faster.

A column-based solution would look like this:

```py
n_arrays = 100
n_columns = 10000
arrays = [
    np.random.randint(0, 10, size=n_columns)
    for n in range(n_arrays)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        row_index: row_array
        for row_index, row_array in enumerate(arrays)
    }
).T
```

Assign your arrays to Pandas columns, then transpose the matrix to turn columns into rows.

Compare the performance to the row-based solution:

```py
In [18]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame({row_index: row_array for row_index, row_array in enumerate(arrays)}).T
6.2 ms ± 21.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(arrays)
1.01 s ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The difference is huge (150x faster).